# What does it mean when someone says “Don't call me ‘boy’!”

Tags: phrase-meaning

Non-native speaker here.

When someone calls another person *boy* and the other person responds by saying “Don't call me ‘boy’”. Does that mean the first person was calling the other person ‘boy’ to imply that he/she is wiser (or smarter or has more experience in life etc.) and the other person rejects that by saying “Don't call me boy”.

I heard this on a YouTube video: *[Last Week Tonight](https://youtu.be/WyGq6cjcc3Q)* with John Oliver. Starting 3:13 to 3:30.

Comment: Why would you assume that “boy” means wiser, smarter, etc?  People who have lived long enough that they consider themselves men, don’t like being labeled as “boy”.

Comment: That's also why you should be careful when you call fully grown women "girl"s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the given context, Alex Jones is trying to belittle John Oliver by saying him "boy". It is derogatory, if you call a fully grown-up man a "boy".

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boy)

> an immature male
>
> > separate the men from the boys

Also, it is an offensive<sup>1</sup> word for a male servant.

---

<sup>1: Check [Entry 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boy) in Merriam Webster</sup>

Answer (score 2):

According to one of my history teachers in high school, whites in the south would call male slaves "boy" regardless of their age... also female slaves "girl" regardless of age.  I recall this was done in "Huckleberry Finn", where even kids were expected to call grown men "boy".

Answer (score 1):

Alex Jones tells John Oliver, not to call him 'boy.' It's obviously a put down the way Oliver says it, "Hey boy, the..." Way back in the late 80's, I was once in a bus in Houston where an older white lady told this young black youth who was standing beside her seat, though there were seats available, "Sit down boy!"
His crushing response was "I got your boy dangling between my legs!" She just sniffed and looked away.

She definitely looked about 70 plus back then and must have lived through WWI, the Depression, WWII, and the Civil Rights movement; antediluvian but not antebellum. That sounds mean but 'boy' is a vocal sneer. It was her Jim Crow etiquette speaking. Her left-over sense of privilege allowed her to say this out loud even in 1988 or so without even thinking that it was demeaning. (I'm saying 'even' in 1988 because I didn't come across too much overt racism back then like there has been this last decade in the US.)

In Dubai we called even older male household help, "houseboys." It sounds so Somerset Maughamish.
Yes, calling someone 'boy' is almost always said sarcastically and to a person of colour, it sounds even more degrading because of the Jim Crow history behind it.

Comment: This history of racist use of *boy* does explain why it is **particularly** offensive when used by a white person to address an adult Black man, but it does not explain its offensiveness when used between two white people (which can still be offensive, but not nearly as strongly).